# Unable to get claims added to my jwt when using jwtsso+oidc in OpenLiberty

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I am securing my frontend in Liberty with openidConnectClient, while also generating a JWT to achieve sso with different other downstream systems. For that I'm trying to benefit from the jwtSso feature to easily generate a JWT based on claims from the oidc's IDToken, however none of them get included. I couldn't find any more documentation about this specific combination (oidc+jwtsso).

Here's my server.xml:

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
  <feature>openidConnectClient-1.0</feature>
  <feature>jwtSso-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
...
<openidConnectClient clientId="..." clientSecret="..." discoveryEndpointUrl="..." id="IBMid" scope="openid" signatureAlgorithm="RS256"
allowCustomCacheKey="false" />
...
<jwtSso jwtBuilderRef="defaultJWT" />
<jwtBuilder id="defaultJWT" issuer="...">
  <claims>email,given_name,family_name,realmName</claims>
</jwtBuilder>
```

This is an example ID token received from OIDC provider:

```
{ "at_hash":"",  
  "aud":"",  
  "email":"jdoe@blah.com",
  "exp":1453872463,  
  "ext":"{\"tenantId\":\"blah.com\"}",  
  "family_name":"Doe",  
  "given_name":"John",  
  "iat":1453872163,  
  "iss":"<issuer>",  
  "name":"John Doe",  
  "preferred_username":"jdoe@blah.com",  
  "realmName":"blah.com",  
  "sub":"120000QGFU",  
  "uniqueSecurityName":"120000QGFU"  
}
```

And this is the final JWT payload that gets generated by jwtSso:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "sub": "120000QGFU",
  "upn": "120000QGFU",
  "realm": "...",
  "iss": "...",
  "exp": 1662499020,
  "iat": 1662491820
}
```

As you can see, none of email,given_name,family_name,realmName claims get included. Can anyone help me understand why the listed claims in jwtbuilder are not part of the generated jwt? I appreciate it in advance